# Python / django / pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

```
<div class="container text-center">

        {% for contact in contacts %}
            <h6>имя пользователя:{{ contact.name_persone }}</h6>
            <h4><a href="/support?page/{{ contact.id }}/">{{ contact.phone_persone }}</a></h4>
            <p>{{ article.article_text }}</p>
            <p><a href="/support?page/{{ contact.id }}/"><img src="{% static hero.jpg %}" width="25px" height="25px"></a>{{ contact.phone_persone }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <ul class="pagination">

            {% if contacts.has_previous %}
                <li><a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a></li>
               <li> <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a></li>
            {% endif %}
             {% for page in contacts.paginator.page_range %}
                        {% if page == contacts.number %}
                            <li class="current"><a href="/support?page/{{ page }}/">{{ page }}</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li><a href="/support?page/{{ page }}/">{{ page }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if contacts.has_next %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page={{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a></li>
            {% endif %}

    </ul></div>
```

Проблема в моей пагинации заключается в том, что если нажимать на номер страницы пагинации, то информация на странице не обновляется, хотя сам URL меняется (пагинация происходит). Не подтягивается информация почему то. Но если я нажимаю на "next" то всё срабатывает корректно.
Подскажите что не так? И может кто-то увидит ещё ошибки, буду благодарен за коррективы!

Comment: Посмотрите на отличие работающей ссылки от неработающей, и всё должно сразу стать понятно.

Comment: Stackoverflow - это не форум, здесь не принято делать в заголовке пометку о решении. Либо просто удалите вопрос, либо напишите под ним ответ и отметьте его решением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас проблема в самой ссылке, которую вы указываете. посмотрите на ссылку страницы, которые не работают:

```py
<li><a href="/support?page/{{ page }}/">{{ page }}</a></li>
```

И на ссылку кнопки `next`, которая работает:

```py
<li><a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a></li>
```

Мало того, что вы в первом случае берете дополнительную часть URL перед вопросительным знаком в виде `/support`, так еще и номер страницы указываете через дробь как часть URL `?page/{{ page }}/`, хотя в работающей ссылке явно используется GET-запрос в виде `"?page={{ page }}"`

В итоге должно получится что-то вроде этого:

```py
{% for page in contacts.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page == contacts.number %}
        <li class="current"><a href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```